# Regular expression in java how do I getting the below output

Tags: java

I need a regular expression to extract content starts with href= to the end of bracket ].How do I do that in java.

```
String s=  [a href="http://myimagefactorycollection.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/
    2db83fcf95c5fc036a00abfb412f50e4.jpg"][a href="https://myimagefactorycollection.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/0e397a47f88e18f8fb91d17db18c7edd-copy.jpg"]

The output should be
"http://myimagefactorycollection.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/
    2db83fcf95c5fc036a00abfb412f50e4.jpg"
"https://myimagefactorycollection.files.w
 ordpress.com/2014/09/0e397a47f88e18f8fb91d17db18c7edd-copy.jpg"
```

Comment: What have you tried? I can only say that String class has methods to find index of specific character and to cut a substring. So go ahead.

Comment: You have 29 question including 4 duplicates of your own question, accepted no answer and failed to show effort for anything. This made me think of you : http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java regular Expression for the below content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931706/java-regular-expression-for-the-below-content)

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\\"(.*)\\\".*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourString);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Explaination:

```
.*   - anything
\\\" - quote (escaped)
(.*) - anything (captured)
\\\" - another quote
.*   - anything
```

Read more about regex [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Giving code solutions without any explanation to someone who doesn't show any effort is, IMHO, not helpful, not even to him...